# Error creating a bean "entityManagerFactory"

Tags: java, spring, maven, javafx

I have a Spring Boot project that uses JavaFX. When i run this project in idea everything works fine, but after i package project using Maven i get this exception when trying to run a jar file

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
Invocation of init method failed;nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

pom.xml is this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these dependencies to your POM:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Maybe you'll need to add versions for the packages.

Comment: Actually helped, thank you! Maybe you also know why method annotated as @PostConstruct doesn't run? Same problem, works in idea, doesn't work in jar file.

Comment: @EmberTraveller I don't think this problem is related to the first... Try asking a new question. But probably some dependency is missing...